# Laravel 4.2 Some time logout automatically.. how to solve this?

Tags: php, laravel, logout

I am creating a commercial website using Laravel 4.2. I use multiple login auth for admin dashboard and user.

My problem is: sometimes page logs out automatically without shown any error. My login code is below. Any ideas?

```
public function userlogin()
{
  $input = Input::all();
  $rules = array(
    'email' => 'required|email',
    'password' => 'required'
    );
  $v = Validator::make($input, $rules);

  if($v->fails())
  {
    return Redirect::to('sign-in')->withInput()->withErrors($v);
  }

  $user = [
    'email' => Input::get('email'),
    'password' => Input::get('password'),
    'status' => 1
  ];

  if (Auth::user()->attempt($user)) {
    return Redirect::to( '/');
  } else {
    Session::flash('failmessage', ' Unable To login !');
    return Redirect::to('sign-in');
  }
}

public function userlogout()
{
  Auth::user()->logout();
  return Redirect::to('/');
}
```

Comment: language and readability

Answer (score 1):

In app/config/session.php you have:

> lifetime

option that allow you to set session expire time in minutes (not in seconds)

```
'lifetime' => 60,
```

means that session will expire after an hour.

There is also one more setting here:

```
'expire_on_close' => true,
```

that decides if session will be expired when browser will be closed.

Try changing the values of those settings as per your need. That will help to solve your problem

Comment: Thank you... and one more question ..how to use remember me option in login function...in laravel

Comment: @Tamilheartz If you have another question ask it by clicking on `Ask Question` on the right top, You should not ask it in comment

Answer (score 0):

You could do what Ashwini G said or you could add the functionality that a user can click the remember me button so that he won't be logged out after the lifetime

For more information about the remember me option check the link below.

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security

Comment: @Tamilheartz Your welcome hoped it helped you somehow :)